# Identify which Storyboard is active

Tags: ios, storyboard

I need to work out how to identify what storyboard is active at any given time. I have a specialised nativation in which I need to identify the storyboard (UIView) then change things programmatically depending on what the user presses.

1. All storyboards have Identifiers.
2. in the viewDidLoad of the root view I have the following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 self.topViewController = 
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"];
{
```

What I would like to do is identify which storyboard the user is on and depending on the press do the following sudo-code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
if (storyboard.name != RootView)
   self.topViewController = 
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"];
{
else if (storyboard.name = View2){
   self.topViewController = 
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View2"];
}
```

etc....

I have step through the code and seen the StoryboardID however it's  which I'm pretty sure your not meant to use....

Thanks in advance
Jeremy

UPDATE: Explanation to Navigation

I'm trying to implement the `ECSlideViewController`, but It's doing my head in. Effectively adding in the slide to the right function to reveal more options. SO, this thinking was going to be easy turned out icky. I have the master `UIViewController<title:HomeView>` I then have 4 buttons on the screen which segueway to other `UIViewControllers<View1>`, `UIViewController<View2>` etc.

In order to produce the effect on View1,View2,View3,View4 I need to bring the class (`ECSlideViewController` as per the example) into the `UIViewController<HomeView>`. However If I change the below code to represent this...

```
self.topViewController = 
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeView"];
```

It crashes because it calls itself. Not good, circular coding is a no no.

but if I set it to what was originally there

```
self.topViewController = 
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstTop"];
```

( btw firstTop is the title of the view used with the example)

It works but then disregards the `UIViewController<HomeView>`

This is why I asked if there was a way to identify the `self.title` of the `UIViewController`(said storyboard...my bad) as I was going to put conditional logic around it in order to not put the code in if it's on the `UIViewController<HomeView>`.

It really is hard to explain unless you download the `ECSlideViewController` and start playing with it. But effectively I just want to test the self.title.....I think...

The other idea was to bring the logic into the `UIViewControllers` of the four and get it to work there...but It freaks out passing nil as it's expecting an identifier...

Hope this makes sense....

J.

Comment: I think you're confused about what a storyboard is. Storyboards don't have identifiers, view controllers and segues do. When you make an app, you automatically get a storyboard, whose file name is MainStoryboard.storyboard. Have you added any other storyboards to your app, or are you talking about view controllers?

Comment: Sorry my bad...yes...I meant view controllers.

Comment: Effectively, I just need to get the title of the UIView...but for the life of me when I use self.title it comes up with the generated number representing the title.

Comment: Do you mean UIView or UIViewController? Why don't you describe the "specialized" navigation you need and someone can probably help you do this more easily using storyboard features.

Comment: Your right Firoze....updated explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay Guys,

Totally ditched ECSlideViewController. I found a few articles explaining that it had issues when you had multiple UiViewControllers not passing data correctly. I ended up using Andrews suggestion. http://www.youtube.com/feed/UCJA_puohXgnze8gPaerTeig  It worked for easier for me.

Although I take note of what the design guidelines Apple have an this is usually a no no, but I'm hoping that they won't mind.

Thanks everyone again!

J.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but it sounds like you will have to compare instances to get the results you are looking for. I haven't tried this, but I would create properties of each storyboard in your app delegate, then reference the app delegate in your view controller to compare. This might not be the best coding practices, but I'll leave that into your hands.

Something like (untested code):

```
- (void)testStoryBoard //After awake from nib or viewDidLoad
 {
    NXAppDelegate *appDelegate = (NXAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([self.storyBoard isEqual:appDelegate.view1StoryBoard]) 
         NSLog(@"View1 Storyboard");
    else 
         NSLog(@"View 2 Storyboard");
 }
```