# How to know the current storyboard name?

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I want to know what is the current loaded storyboard,I used the below code but it is still get me the Main storyboard not the current.

```
//This get me the Main storyboard 
[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are working in a UIViewController class that is instantied or segues through the storyboard the most simple way is :

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = self.storyboard;
```

If you are in a UIView class that is in a UIViewController

```
UIResponder *responder = self;
while (![responder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
    responder = [responder nextResponder];
    if (nil == responder) {
        break;
    }
}
UIViewController *viewController = (UIViewController *) responder;
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = viewController.storyboard;
```

Comment: how i can get the name ??

Answer (score 34):

Building on Durican's answer above:

Within a view controller:

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = self.storyboard;
NSString * storyboardName = [storyboard valueForKey:@"name"];
```

(The name will not include the ".storyboard" filename extension.)

Comment: Question. How did you come up with this? The documentation doesn't say anything about a name property. I don't see a way to query all the keys either. Did you take a stab at it from the IB labels?

Comment: Just a complete guess, I tested it and it turns out I was right. :)

Comment: This is private API so be careful.

Answer (score -3):

Just do this, this may solve your query

```
NSString *storyboardName;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    storyboardName = @"iPad";
} else {
    storyboardName = @"iPhone";
}
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
```

Comment: may be you don't understand my question , i want to know the name not set the name of storyboard

Comment: Have you gone through this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928817/identify-which-storyboard-is-active