# How can I access a view controller's storyboard id programatically

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I've tried `self.view.accessibilityIdentifier` and `storyboard?.accessibilityAttributedLabel`, neither of those contain the storyboard id value. So what does?

EDIT: I've found outdated answers to this question, nothing for swift 4 or recent xcode version

[How to know the current storyboard name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17723732/how-to-know-the-current-storyboard-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in ViewDidLoad if you have "Use Storyboard ID" set to "yes" in the identity inspector:

```
if let str = self.restorationIdentifier {
//Do something with the View Controller's Storyboard ID
}
```

Comment: Why did you declare `str` as `String!` instead of `String?` ? Or better yet, just do `let str = self.restorationIdentifier`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "endGame") as! EndViewController

        present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

on the storyboard in identity inspector put your storyboard Id in, mine was "endGame" and also you need to add a new cocoa touch class then also in identity inspector you need to add that ViewControllers name in there. mine was EndViewController. Then use the code above.

Comment: just to add on to that, be sure on your storyboard you have selected the ViewController your wishing to access. for example In my code I was accessing my end screen of a game. so on my playing ViewController I Entered that code into my function that Ends the game. so when a user ends they access my EndGame ViewController.